Libertinus Math with pdfLaTeX?
When used with lualatex, the libertinus package sets up both text and math fonts. With pdflatex, only the text fonts seem to be set up.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$

\end{document}

With lualatex:

With pdflatex:

I would like to use both the text and math fonts for my project but I am required to use pdflatex. Is there any way to use the matching math font with pdflatex?

For compilation under pdfLaTeX, I suggest you load both libertinust1math and libertinus.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex % document is being compiled under pdfLaTeX
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{libertinus,libertinust1math}
\else % XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is used to compile the document
   %\usepackage{unicode-math} % optional
   \usepackage{libertinus}
\fi
\begin{document}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

$ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$

\end{document}

